# JQuery Auto Complete max results shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How do you show more than 10 results with JQuery UI Autocomplete?

I've tried:

```
.autocomplete({
    max: 50
});
```

with no luck. Any Ideas?

Comment: What are you using as the source of the autocomplete?

Comment: jquery ui: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: are you sure there are more than 10 results? What does the datasource return when you call it directly?

Comment: what i mean by source is what are you passing into the `source: []` parameter? http://http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: sorry for the bogus question, it was a server side bug, I was limiting my results to 10 and didn't realize it. I was blaming jquery ui for my bug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applications that I have JQuery UI autocomplete implemented use the database query to limit the results to X amount.

It's been my experience that JQuery UI autocomplete will list anything you throw at that matches.